# How to output the rest of a string from a specific letter in Python?

Tags: python, string

I am given a input string like 'abcdefga'. While iterating over this string, I want to output every substring beginning with the letter next to the actual one.
For example: when the program picks the first 'a', I wish my output like: 'bcdefga'.

```
string = 'abcdefga'
for letter in string: 
    print( ??? )
#output for the first letter should be: 'bcdefga'
#and so on ...
```

Comment: Do you want to print an empty string at the last?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.index()` to get the index of first occurrence of the char in your string. And then use *string slicing* to get the remaining string from that index. For example:

```
#                                 v "+1" to pick position of next char in string
>>> my_string[my_string.index('b')+1:]
'cdefga'
```

In case any character passed to the `str.index()` doesn't exists in your string, it'll raise `ValueError` exception which you can handle using `try/except` block.

---

To get the list of all the string skipping start characters at a time, you can use *string slicing* in loop as:

```
for i, c in enumerate(my_string):
    print('current char "{}", remaining string: {}'.format(c, my_string[i+1:]))

# Output:
current char "a", remaining string: bcdefga
current char "b", remaining string: cdefga
current char "c", remaining string: defga
current char "d", remaining string: efga
current char "e", remaining string: fga
current char "f", remaining string: ga
current char "g", remaining string: a
current char "a", remaining string:
```

Comment: He wants to do this while iterating over the string, first code is buggy in such a usage.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is to instead use the index (`enumerate` will give you an `idx`, `value` pair for each element in the list):

```
string = 'abcdefga'

for idx, letter in enumerate(string): 
    print(string[idx+1:])
```

Another option is to use `index` to find the location of the first substring, but your second `a` will use the first index in that case (if you're not tracking the index):

```
string = 'abcdefga'

for letter in string: 
    print(string[string.index(letter)+1:])
```

The `[start:end]` syntax returns a slice of the string, while `index` returns the first occurence of the letter in the string / element in the list.

Comment: `for i in range(len(foo)):` is "unpythonic", ugly and performs worse. `enumerate` is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

You can slice the string:

```py
string = 'abcdefga'

for i, c in enumerate(string):
    # print all the characters which comes after first `i+1` characters 
    # `c` is current character
    print(string[i+1:], c, sep = ", ")
```

Output:

```py
bcdefga, a
cdefga, b
defga, c
efga, d
fga, e
ga, f
a, g
, a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = 'abcdefga'
for index in range(1,len(string)):
    print( string[index:] )
```

`[index:]` slices the string from index to the end.

Comment: This exacly the same as my answer, why post the same thing?

Comment: @EkremDinçel Because I did not see yours before I submited mine. You wer just a little bit faster at Typing. No harm done.